# Transparent background spanning several tikzpictures

Tags: tikz-pgf, watermark

I am trying to display a "forbidden sign" in the background of
two tikzpictures (much like some kind of watermark).
However, in the following MWE the "forbidden sign" is cut-off at some
seemingly arbitrary horizontal line.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,shapes}

\begin{document}
\noindent
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[green] (0.0, -5.0) rectangle (10.0, 0.0);
  \end{tikzpicture}\\
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[blue] (0.0, -5.0) rectangle (10.0, 0.0);
    \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
      \begin{scope}[opacity=0.5,transparency group,overlay]
        \draw node[forbidden sign,
                   minimum size=5cm,
                   line width=2ex,
                   draw=red,
                   fill=white] at (5.0,0.0) {Test};
      \end{scope}
    \end{pgfonlayer}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Do you have any idea how I can fix this behaviour?

Comment: You need to  remove `overlay`

Comment: @Altermundus: I think it is not sufficient in this case simply removing `overlay`. That was my first attempt, but then the pictures were not more near.

Comment: When I remove overlay, the "forbidden sign" does not span the first tikzpicture.

Comment: I would like to say : remove from the node option but I don't know exactly what result is desired.

Comment: Why don't you use directly a watermark as given in the manual? It's much more simpler.

Comment: @percusse yes but the problem here it's to understand exactly what Aton wants to get. One tikzpicture, two ? or three ? How to place these pictures. Forbidden sign in the background for all the pictures ? there are a lot of possibilities !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems difficult to use `overlay` with `transparency group`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,shapes}
\pgfdeclarelayer{myback}    
\pgfsetlayers{myback,main}
\newsavebox{\mybox}   
\begin{document}
\parindent=0pt 

\savebox{\mybox}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[transparency group,opacity=.5]
        \node[forbidden sign,
              minimum size=5cm,
              line width=2ex,
              draw=red,
              fill=white]  {};
\end{tikzpicture}} 

  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[green] (0.0, -5.0) rectangle (10.0, 0.0);
  \end{tikzpicture}\\ \baselineskip=0pt     
 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \draw[blue] (0.0, -5.0) rectangle (10.0, 0.0);
      \begin{pgfonlayer}{myback}
    \node[inner sep=0pt] (s) at (5,0){\usebox\mybox};
    \end{pgfonlayer} 
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but there is other ways to get this.

Comment: That is almost the result I would like to achieve. However I would like the two intersections of the line and the circle to have the same color. That is why I tried using "transparency group" in the first place. See pgfmanual, section 20.4 "Transparency Groups".

Comment: A list of requests at the beginning of the first question is a better way to get a good answer :) Do you need two pictures ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That seems to work. You mentioned that there are ``other ways to get this''. Could you elaborate on that? For clarification: in general I would like to be able to place watermark-like tikzpictures anywhere on the page relative to an existing-node. Btw, I searched the pgfmanual for 'watermark' but did not find a solution.

Comment: There are some packages to place a picture on a page (eso-pic,watermark etc.) Here the problem seems to be a conflict between `remember picture`, `overlay` and `transparency group`. Finally it's difficult to avoid this problem because you need `remember picture` and `overlay` to place a picture in a page. Perhaps you need to wait another solution.

Comment: Please what is `\useasboundingbox(0.0,0)rectangle(0.0,0.0)` for?

Comment: @Altermundus: Since your solution works for my initial question, I'll accept it as the final answer. Thanks!

Comment: @AhmedMusa Something that I forgot to remove :)